# How to convert a keycode to an char in python?

Tags: python, keycode

I'm writing a program in Linux which reads and distinguish inputs from two USB devices(two barcode readers) which simulates a keyboard.

I've already can read inputs from USB, but it happens before OS translate keycode in a charactere.

<strike>For example, when I read 'a' i got 24, 'b' 25, etc....</strike>

For example, when I read 'a' i got 4, 'b' 5, etc....

Is there any way to convert that code in a char without manual mapping?

Some output exemples:

KEYPRESS = a output = **array('B', [0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])**

KEYPRESS = SHIFT + a output = **array('B', [2, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])**

KEYPRESS = 1 output = **array('B', [0, 0, 30, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])**

KEYPRESS = ENTER output =  **array('B', [0, 0, 81, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])**

thx!

Answer (score 4):

Use the [chr](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#chr) function. Python uses a different character mapping ([ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#ASCII_printable_characters)) from whatever you're receiving though, so you will have to add 73 to your key values to fix the offset.

```
>>> chr(24 + 73)
'a'
>>> chr(25 + 73)
'b'
```

Comment: Thank you! It's a good solution, but it works only for alphabetic chars.
4 + 93 = 97
but when I press '1' i've read 30
30 + 93 != 49

Answer (score 2):

> I've already can read inputs from USB, but it happens before OS
>   translate keycode in a charactere.
>   
>   <strike>The problem seems to me in your interface or the driver program.</strike>

In ASCII 'a' is supposed to have ordinal value 97 whose binary representation is `0b1100001`, where as what you are receiving is 27 whose binary representation is `0b11000`, similarly for 'b' you were supposed to received '0b1100010' instead you received 25 which is `0b11001`. Check your hardware to determine if the 1st and the 3rd bit is dropped from the input.

What you are receiving is USB scan code. I do not think there is a third party python library to do the conversion for you. I would suggest you to refer any of the [USB Scan Code Table](http://www.win.tue.nl/~aeb/linux/kbd/scancodes-14.html) and from it, create a dictionary of USB Scan Code vs the corresponding  ASCII.

Comment: Thank you Abhijit, but my receive data is correct. I've made a mistake in my post, but i've already fixed it.

Comment: Thank you again Abhijit!
I will search if pythonusb or other third party have this method!
Your answer is very useful, sorry but i don't have sufficient level to mark it.